# multiple joins left joins access / subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

The following code works OK in MS Access. However, I'm trying to add a further left join. My left join will join a query rather than a table.

Hope this makes sense.

Appreciate the help

```
SELECT 
    a.[business unit], 
    b.[Total Colleagues in DMS], 
    Sum(IIf([a].[Session Date] Is Not Null,1,0)) AS [Total Bookings],
    Sum([a.Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)]) AS [Total Cancellations], 
    (Sum(IIf([a].[Session Date] Is Not Null,1,0))-Sum([a.Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)])) AS [Net Bookings], 
    Sum([a.lookup_attended]) AS Attended, 
    (b.[Total Colleagues in DMS]-(Sum(IIf([a].[Session Date] Is Not Null,1,0))-Sum([a.Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)]))) AS [Unbooked Spaces] 
FROM 
    everything AS a  
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        a.[business unit], count(*) AS [Total Colleagues in DMS] 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            a.lookup_id, 
            A.[BUSINESS UNIT] 
        FROM 
            EVERYTHING AS a 
        WHERE 
            (a.status<>"leaver" Or a.status<>"Not in scope") 
            And 
            A.PROJECT Is Null
     )  AS [%$##@_Alias] 
     GROUP BY 
         a.[business unit]
 )  AS b 
 ON 
     a.[business unit] = b.[business unit]
WHERE 
(
    ((a.status)<>"leaver" Or (a.status)<>"not in scope")    
GROUP BY 
    a.[business unit], 
    b.[Total Colleagues in DMS], 
    b.[business unit];
```

Comment: you need to give more information when asking a question for example:  What is the name of the query you're trying to join?  How does it relate to the existing tables listed?  whats the carnality between that join and the other tables as the sum's may be off once you add this query.

Comment: What's not working about it? After reformatting your SQL, there's a missing `)` in your `WHERE` statement. Are you just encountering a syntax error? Can you post the exact error message, if any?

Comment: Tables can indeed be a query (derived table, VIEW, stored Query object). To join a third table you need to put the first two in parens e.g. `SELECT  * FROM (T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id) JOIN T3 ON T1.id = T3.id` (noting the optimizer isn't required to honour the specified order).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but *MS Access* + *additional LEFT JOIN* makes me think that your main problem is that you made the additional LEFT JOIN in a query that you have not shown above, and that you did not surrounded your tables with parentheses which is required in MS ACCESS SQL if you have more than one JOIN. Which gave you an error.

If I am plain wrong you should better explain what your problem is.

So this would **not** work :

```
SELECT 
    a.[business unit], 
    b.[Total Colleagues in DMS], 
    Sum(IIf([a].[Session Date] Is Not Null,1,0)) AS [Total Bookings],
    Sum([a.Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)]) AS [Total Cancellations], 
    (Sum(IIf([a].[Session Date] Is Not Null,1,0))-Sum([a.Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)])) AS [Net Bookings], 
    Sum([a.lookup_attended]) AS Attended, 
    (b.[Total Colleagues in DMS]-(Sum(IIf([a].[Session Date] Is Not Null,1,0))-Sum([a.Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)]))) AS [Unbooked Spaces] 
FROM 
    everything AS a  
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        a.[business unit], count(*) AS [Total Colleagues in DMS] 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            a.lookup_id, 
            A.[BUSINESS UNIT] 
        FROM 
            EVERYTHING AS a 
        WHERE 
            (a.status<>"leaver" Or a.status<>"Not in scope") 
            And 
            A.PROJECT Is Null
     )  AS [%$##@_Alias] 
     GROUP BY 
         a.[business unit]
 )  AS b 
 ON 
     a.[business unit] = b.[business unit]
LEFT JOIN your_query AS q ON q.whatever=a.whatever    

WHERE 
(
    ((a.status)<>"leaver" Or (a.status)<>"not in scope")    
GROUP BY 
    a.[business unit], 
    b.[Total Colleagues in DMS], 
    b.[business unit];
```

But this will work :

```
SELECT 
    a.[business unit], 
    b.[Total Colleagues in DMS], 
    Sum(IIf([a].[Session Date] Is Not Null,1,0)) AS [Total Bookings],
    Sum([a.Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)]) AS [Total Cancellations], 
    (Sum(IIf([a].[Session Date] Is Not Null,1,0))-Sum([a.Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)])) AS [Net Bookings], 
    Sum([a.lookup_attended]) AS Attended, 
    (b.[Total Colleagues in DMS]-(Sum(IIf([a].[Session Date] Is Not Null,1,0))-Sum([a.Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)]))) AS [Unbooked Spaces] 
FROM 
   (( everything AS a  
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        a.[business unit], count(*) AS [Total Colleagues in DMS] 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            a.lookup_id, 
            A.[BUSINESS UNIT] 
        FROM 
            EVERYTHING AS a 
        WHERE 
            (a.status<>"leaver" Or a.status<>"Not in scope") 
            And 
            A.PROJECT Is Null
     )  AS [%$##@_Alias] 
     GROUP BY 
         a.[business unit]
 )  AS b 
 ON 
     a.[business unit] = b.[business unit] )
LEFT JOIN your_query AS q ON q.whatever=a.whatever )

WHERE 
(
    ((a.status)<>"leaver" Or (a.status)<>"not in scope")    
GROUP BY 
    a.[business unit], 
    b.[Total Colleagues in DMS], 
    b.[business unit];
```

Notice the left parentheses after the `FROM` and right parentheses after each `ON` clause